# Git Actions Job fails because of Username and Password required

Tags: python, docker, github, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run a job on push using Git Actions, however it fails every time saying username and password required.

here's my code

```
---
name: Checks

on: [push]

jobs:
  test-lints:
    name: Test and Lint
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        run: echo ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }} | docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USER }} --password-stdin
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Test
        run: docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py test"
      - name: Linting
        run: docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "flake8"
```

But this is what it shows on the repository action page

[image: Error message on Actions Tab on GitHub]

Comment: have you confirmed you set secrets in gh repo under actions? DOCKERHUB_USER for example.

Comment: No I haven't. I have only set it in my secret. How do I confirm it under actions?

Comment: @DeveloperMaleek Here is a [guide](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets), including steps on how to set up secrets. I'm also pretty sure you can't use secrets directly in the command, you need to set an environment variable instead

Comment: I will check that out. Thanks.

Comment: I have checked out the link, but I figured out that I had followed the same procedure to setup my secrets

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have configured secret keys in correct place.

Link should be:

```
https://github.com/{github_account}/{project_name}/settings/secrets/actions
```

On this page you should have both `DOCKERHUB_TOKEN` and `DOCKERHUB_USER`.
If you don't have them, create new tocken [here](https://hub.docker.com/settings/security).